# Pun in Alternate opening scene for Watson and Holmes?

Tags: holmes-and-watson

I saw a Russian cam of Holmes and Watson. Apparently, the opening is different from the US opening. This opening scene takes place in a garden.

The video and sound was blurry but was the large vegetable Holmes tended a cucumber?

If so, the scene takes place in a cumber patch, which I think is a reference to actor Benedict Cumberbatch who played Holmes in another production.

Comment: I've never heard a cucumber referred to as a "cumber patch", "cucumber patch" would be more accurate, but "cumber" isn't really a different term for "cucumber". I've heard them referred to as "cukes", but never "cumbers".

Comment: Also it's Benedict Cumberbatch not Cumberpatch....

Comment: @RonBeyer True, but a pun is a "play on words" (and there is more than one way to do that) meaning that even if "cumber" batch is not accurate term for a cucumber group/garden or that 'cumber', in the context of his surname's etymology, is not associated with a cucumber, it wouldn't be hard to "imagine" the 'cumber part taken as 'slang' to make jump. A batch or a patch are still quantities of things presented in "groups" as patches are in gardens and then you can take a batch from the patch. I'm not say'n I know for certain it's an intentional pun or not, but I can see how it could be.

Comment: The fruit in question is what is know in British English as a marrow, the mature form of a courgette, growing giant marrows is a popular pass time for British gardeners who display them at flowers show and other events.https://www.telegraph.co.uk/gardening/how-to-grow/in-pictures--giant-vegetables-at-the-40th-harrogate-autumn-flowe/giant-marrow/

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the pun, but at least it is [true](https://movieweb.com/holmes-and-watson-alternate-opening-scene-mandela-effect/) that there is an alternate opening scene.

> Holmes (is) in a garden tending to some papaya-looking plant, and smacking it and calling it a dirty b*tch, and narrating that Watson had come back from a war in Afghanistan. Then, Watson tries to jump off of 221B Baker Street into the garden. Holmes keeps trying to tell him to jump into the other garden, but Watson slips off and smashes the plant, and writhes around in it, and Holmes tells him to stop.

As comments have mentioned, if those fruit were indeed cucumbers, it would be a **cucumber patch**, not a cumber patch. I haven't found any info regarding this and whether or not it would be a reference to [Benedict Cucumberbatch](https://i.imgflip.com/1fd2bw.jpg).